# Can we use any other TAG inside <ul> along with <li>?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, w3c

Can we use any other TAG in `<ul>` along with `<li>`?

like

```
<ul>
Some text here or <p>Some text here<p> etc
<li>item 1</li>
Some text here or <p>Some text here<p> etc
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I could understand it if you were using `<ol>` and trying to get a list continuation, but there doesn't seem to be any point putting a paragraph inside an unordered list wrapper (as well as it being invalid, obv).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For your code to be valid you can't put any tag inside a `<ul>` other than an `<li>`.

You can however, put any block level element inside the `<li>`, like so:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <h2>...</h2>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about `script`, `noscript`, ev. `ins` and `del`? I want to mark some intervals with something that is not really rendered, but that _may_ put into `ul`.

Comment: @herby : Why not put it after the `<ul>`??

Comment: @JonnyHaynes: I want something for _marking_ begin and end of the interval. For example a range of `li`s inside `ul`. I have used empty `<script>`s and it works for me.

Comment: What are your thoughts on why around line 180, it has non-li elements directly inside a UL element?
https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/app/index.html

Comment: @johnsnails the code's invalid. Looks like a typo. I've raised a pull request to get it fixed.

Comment: what about the `<meta>` tag with an `itemprop` attribute?

Comment: @chharvey not valid according to the [W3C validator](https://s31.postimg.org/jc2evhsmz/Screen_Shot_2016_07_22_at_12_10_49.png)

Answer (score 14):

According to the [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), the basic structure of a list must be:

```
<UL>
   <LI> ... first list item...
   <LI> ... second list item...
   ...
</UL>
```

You can put `p` tags only inside of `li` tags, not as direct children of `ul`. The W3C Recommendation expressly states:

> lists are made up of sequences of list items defined by the LI element

Answer (score 6):

You can use template tag and it is totally legal. For example:

```
<ul>
<template>Some text here or <p>Some text here<p> etc</template>
<li>item 1</li>
<template>Some text here or <p>Some text here<p> etc</template>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any reference for this?

Comment: It is given in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)
Allowed tags are LI, SCRIPT and TEMPLATE

Answer (score 5):

While you could have other tags inside (and it might work just fine), you shouldn't because it's not w3c-compliant. It also makes very little semantic sense.

Just create a simple page and run it throught the validator ( http://validator.w3.org/ ) and you'll see for yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

No, this would be invalid markup. However, if you're trying to achieve a different look and feel for some of the lines, you can do this by adding a specific classname to any li tag instead. See below:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foobar">Label</li>
    <li>Some text here</li>
    <li>Some text here</li>
    <li class="foobar">Label</li>
    <li>Some text here</li>
    <li>Some text here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can** write such mark up but you **shouldn't** as it is non-compliant and you may get strange and unexpected results in different browsers.

Comment: no offense but this answer is not really helpful. I'm sure the OP knows they are physically capable of typing the markup; I'm sure they asked the question to find out whether it was *valid* or not.

Comment: 1) Well in all objective honesty, this answer could have been more helpful had you provided a link or example code or something. 2) My assumptions about the OP are not that far-fetched. It's clear in their code they are aware they can type the markup, and any reasonable person can infer as to why they asked the question. 3) And you're right, my comment probably wasn't that helpful—next time I'll just downvote without justifying?

Answer (score 1):

we can't put any tag inside  ul other than li.
However, we can put other tags inside li, like this::

```
<ul>
<li>
  <div>
    <h2>Some Dummmy text</h2>
    <p> some content </p>
    --- 
    ---
  </div>
<li/>
<li><li/>
<li><li/>
----
----
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your doing this to style a part of the list-element, you could do this

```
<ul>
  <li>normal text <span>bold text</span></li>
  <li>normal text <span>bold text</span></li>
</ul>
```

and then use the CSS

```
ul li {font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;}
ul li span {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Downvote: Why use a span with `font-weight: bold;` when you could easily and more importantly, it'll be more semantic to use the `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout.js specific answer, you can use the following comment syntax.

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Header item</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
        <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        myItems: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 quote**

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element says that `ul` has:

> Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

"Content model" means what we can put inside the element.

Therefore, from this we understand that only `li` things like `script` are allowed.

Compare that to an element like `div` which https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element says:

> If the element is not a child of a dl element: flow content.

The definition of "flow content" is then a huge list that contains most tags:

> a, abbr, address, ..., text

Also note how `text` is present in there. We then see its definition https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content

> Text, in the context of content models, means either nothing, or Text nodes. Text is sometimes used as a content model on its own, but is also phrasing content, and can be inter-element whitespace (if the Text nodes are empty or contain just ASCII whitespace).

"Inter-element whitespace is then defined as:

> ASCII whitespace is always allowed between elements. User agents represent these characters between elements in the source markup as Text nodes in the DOM. Empty Text nodes and Text nodes consisting of just sequences of those characters are considered inter-element whitespace.

and "ASCII whitespace" as https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content

> ASCII whitespace is U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, or U+0020 SPACE.

From all of this, besides the previously mentioned `li` and `script` tags, I believe only the above whitespaces are allowed within a `ul`.

The HTML5 validator agrees with that theory: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score -1):

No. If it's list, it has list-items in it. I can't see any use for list with non-list-items in it; it's not list...