# Is anything except LI's allowed in a UL?

Tags: html

We're getting some suspicious HTML from our designer. Is the following valid?  (note the UL inside the UL)

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <ul>    
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
        <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <ul>    
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
        <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use any other TAG inside <ul> along with <li>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [HTML 4 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-UL), the [XHTML 2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-list.html#edef_list_ul) and the [HTML 5 specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-ul-element) that code is invalid.

#### HTML 4

> <!ELEMENT `UL` - - (`LI`)+

This means that inside a `<ul>` there can only be multiple `<li>` elements.

#### XHTML

> Both types of lists (`ul|ol`) are made up of sequences of list items defined by the **`li`** element.

**HTML 5**

> **Content model**:
>       Zero or more [**`li`**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) and [**script-supporting**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) elements.

Note that script-supporting elements are elements that are not rendered, and currently include only `<script>` and `<template>`.

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not valid. The only allowed elements inside `ul` are `li`.

Corrected sample:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>1</span>
        <ul>    
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
            <li>1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>2</span>
        <ul>    
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
            <li>1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Don't allow your designer to write any HTML code for you. Hire a front-end developer that really knows how to deal with HTML and XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed not valid; what was probably meant is:

```
<ul>
  <li>1
    <ul>
    <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, what is your designer doing writing the HTML?

Comment: Often developers that work on the front-end are just called designers. She might not actually mean that her graphic designer is writing code, not that they should not, HTML is not hard to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't valid. To create nested lists, you have to put the `ul` tag inside a `li` tag:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>
    <ul>    
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
        <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>
    <ul>    
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
        <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should search for HTML standards information at W3C site. For list elements you can find it here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/ul. It says that **ul should only contain li** elements. In your code nested ul's should be placed inside li's.

Answer (score 1):

Its invalid. I just ran a check against [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org)

Here is the error

> Line 6, Column 8: document type does
>   not allow element "ul" here; assuming
>   missing "li" start-tag

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it not valid, but `<li>1</li>` isn't necessary. Why not:

```html
<ol>
  <li>&nbsp; <!--if no content, some browsers render nested li on same line-->
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>&nbsp;
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```