# Tag H3 inside UL tag

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is anything except LI's allowed in a UL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul)

I was doing something like that:

```
<ul>
    <h3><a name="titlename">Title</a></h3>
    <li>Text.</li>
    <li>More text.</li>
    <span><a href="/url">Click here</a> to go to some place.</span>
</ul>
```

But i get warnings in visual studio:

```
Warning Validation (HTML5): Element 'h3' cannot be nested within element 'ul'.  
Warning Validation (HTML5): Element 'span' cannot be nested within element эul'.
```

I googled and [found](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?519684-h3-tag-inside-ul) that looks like it is not a problem to have another tags but `<li>` inside `<ul>`ю

But anyway may be some one have any opinions on that. Could it break something? do put you `<h>` tags or any another tags inside `<ul>`? What is your experience with that?

Comment: You already have the answer in the post you linked to. Opinions change nothing, it just the way it works.

Answer (score 6):

`<ul>` denotes an unordered list, while `<li>` denotes a list item that belongs to that unordered list - so it only really makes sense to have `<li>` elements within a `<ul>` element. If you want to give the unordered list a title, do it *outside* of the list (this would be the more 'normal' way), or within an `<li>` element that is inside the list.

```
<h3>My List Title</h3>
<ul>
  <li>List items in here...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is invalid if your `<h3>` is a child of the `<ul>`. You can only have it inside a `<li>` but not directly in a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put inside ot `<UL>` tag only `<LI>`. And then in LI you can put what you want.

```
<ul>
   <li><h3><a name="titlename">Title</a></h3></li>
   <li>Text.</li>
   <li>More text.</li>
   <li><span><a href="/url">Click here</a> to go to some place.</span></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<h3><a name="titlename">Title</a></h3>
<ul>
   <li>Text.</li>
   <li>More text.</li>
</ul>
<span><a href="/url">Click here</a> to go to some place.</span>
```

Yes, you can put anything you want inside of UL, but it's not by W3C standarts (you can see the validation errors) and nobody will guarantie you that in all browsers it will be displayed properly.