# :first-child selector or equivelant

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style the first list item of a UL, the list item is encased in an `<a>` tag.

I would have thought it would be simple, just this: http://jsfiddle.net/PHhFX/ but that isn't working.

Anyone any clue?

Comment: Your HTML is completely invalid. You cannot wrap LI is any tags.

Comment: Basically it's wrong that you but `<li></li>` in `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not supposed to encase a `<li>` in an `<a>` — in your HTML you can only have your `<li>` elements as children of the `<ul>`.

You probably meant to do it the other way around (`<a>` within `<li>`), then select

```
ul li:first-child
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PHhFX/3)

Comment: My bad, completely missed the fact my HTML markup was wrong.

If anyone is interested, I did find a fix (for my incorrect markup) and that was `ul a:first-child li {}`

Comment: @user1538100 mate it's invalid to put `<li>` in `<a>` tag!

Comment: @skmasq: He already knows that, but that doesn't preclude the selector from working. Of course, it's still best to change the markup instead...

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PHhFX/11/

**CSS** markup:

```
ul li:first-child {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML** markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="a">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="b">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="c">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
```

*p.s.:* you shouldn't wrap `<li>` elements with `<a>` elements. Remember, after a `<ul>` comes a `<li>`

Hope it helps! ​

Comment: Laughing right now the time it took me to create post you already posted :D Nice one though.

Comment: @skmasq hahaha the evil one here is BoltClock, he made an edit 5 secs after the question was post and answered it like 15 secs later! :'(

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, fixed your html and css:

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="a">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="b">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="c">AAA</a></li>
</ul>​
```

And css:

```
ul li:first-child {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}    ​
```

Here is live example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHhFX/16/)

Answer (score 1):

[The HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-li-element) details that the `li` element may be contained by the following elements:

- `ol`
- `ul`
- `menu`

You'll note that `a` is not among them.

Answer (score 0):

Link tags are not valid children of lists (`<ul>` or `<ol>`) see: [Is anything except LI's allowed in a UL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul)

You must have the links inside the list-items:

```
<li><a href="a">AAA</a></li>
```

and so:

```
ul li:first-child a{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/PHhFX/17/

Answer (score 0):

Use  `ul a:first-child>li`  ​instead of ul `a:first-child ​` but this is a hack.
Border is not inherited property.