# WordPress: Add HTML to navigation menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, navigation

```
<ul id="menu-primary">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <span></span> /* Add after the list items; before the closing </ul> tag */
</ul>
```

How to add `<span>` tags after the list items, to the WP-menu with `id="menu-primary"`?

**EDIT**

```
<ul id="menu-primary">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li><li class="fix"></li> /* Add <li class="fix"></li> adjacent after the list items exactly as shown. */
</ul>
```

Comment: span tag is not allowed inside the ul tag:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul

Comment: You're right. It seems to work but I guess I shouldn't mess around with it.

Comment: You need a custom walker to modify the menu but obviously with valid markup, here is a [tutorial about this](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class for the li ?

```
<ul id="menu-primary">
    <li class ="class"></li>
    <li class ="class"></li>
    <li class ="class"></li>
/* Add after the list items; before the closing </ul> tag */
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying to fix a little quirk similar to the first answer in this question (read at the very end): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs/6880421#6880421