# Masking issue when sliding multiple divs behind a line

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a `CSS` animation effect that's difficult to implement due to *layering* problems. See the snippet below:

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

function toggleF() {
  'use strict';
  document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('fuzzyState');
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleF);
```

```css
body {
  height: 90%;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center overflow:hidden;
}

button {
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#toggle {
  float: left;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 150%
}

#toggle:hover {
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

#toggle:active {
  background: #022;
  color: #fff
}

nav ul:after {
  content"";
  display: block;
  clear: both
}

nav ul {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 150%
}

nav li {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

nav button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

nav button:hover {
  background: #022;
  color: #eee
}

nav button:active {
  background: #033;
  color: #fff
}

ul hr {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2
}

nav.fuzzyState #dos {
  transform: translateX(230px)
}

nav.fuzzyState #uno {
  transform: translateX(400px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px)
}

nav.fuzzyState #tres {
  /*transform:translateX(-230px)*/
}

nav #tres {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}

#leftNavMask {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 356px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: justify;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#rightNavMask {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 156px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: justify;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1
}

#dos,
#tres {
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out
}

#uno {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, -webkit-filter 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">+</button>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="uno"><button>uno</button></li>
    <li id="dos"><button>dos</button></li>
    <hr>
    <li id="tres"><button>tres</button></li>

    <div id="leftNavMask"></div>
    <div id="rightNavMask"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

After the `+` button is clicked my goal is to make the `tres` button slide to the left while being masked just like the `uno` and `dos` buttons, except in the opposite direction. It seems impossible to pull off because whatever `z-index` I give any elements there's no way to have the left mask on top of the correct elements while simultaneously having the right mask do its job. Are there any simple ways to do this without `jQuery`? Thanks.

**To clarify**: The `uno` and `dos` buttons are currently going *under* a `div` that is colored to match the background. I need the `tres` button to slide left *under* a second `div` that is somehow on top of the `tres` button to mask it but also below the `uno` and `dos` buttons so they aren't blocked at the beginning.

Comment: So 1 and 2 are acting correct, but you want 3 to slide to the left behind that line?

Comment: @Leeish, Precisely. If you uncomment the code in my CSS for `nav.fuzzyState #tres` you'll be able to see what happens. #3 just over laps the other divs.

Comment: I don't think it can be done but I'm up voting to see if someone can. The stacking order you want with z-index is impossible. You could probably do some crazy timing with javascript but I'll be interested in seeing if someone can pull it off without JS.

Comment: @Leeish looks like we have a winner.

Comment: Duh. I was stuck trying to use stacking like you. Overflow works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since this question was asked, therefore, most probably you have found a solution already. But just in case, here you have a possible approach to what you wanted to achieve.

Instead of using absolute positioned divs with the same color of the background to cover the animated `li` elements, why don't use an `overflow` `hidden` property in the `ul` container? If you do this, the `ul` will act as a "mask" and when the `li` elements get animated outside the `ul`, they will be automatically "hidden". Take a look at your snippet already modified using this approach (I have used two `ul` elements to animate the `li` elements separately):

> I saw that you placed an `hr` (and two `div`) inside the `ul` element and a `ul` [should only contain `li` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul). For this solution, I used a pseudo-element to mimic the vertical line.

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

function toggleF() {
  document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('fuzzyState');
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleF);
```

```css
body {
  color: #222;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

#toggle {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #666;
  float: left;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 38px;
}

#toggle:hover {
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  user-select: none;
}

#toggle:active {
  background: #022;
  color: #fff
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul.left::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 140px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
  user-select: none;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out;
  width: 140px;
}

nav button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}

nav button:hover {
  background: #022;
  color: #eee;
}

nav button:active {
  background: #033;
  color: #fff;
}

nav.fuzzyState ul > li {
  pointer-events: none;
}

nav.fuzzyState ul.left > li {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

nav.fuzzyState ul.right > li {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">+</button>
<nav>
  <ul class="left">
    <li><button>uno</button></li>
    <li><button>dos</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><button>tres</button></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```