# Bootstrap Popover content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button which triggers a popover. It is generated by another script.

```
$('#appendTarget').append('<div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">' + item.name +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="showPopover(this)"><b style="color: red"><img src="Img/gear.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px"></b></button>');
```

This is my function for triggering:

```
function showPopover(element) {
    $(element).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            $('#popover-content').append('<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>'
                                        +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Activate</a>'
                                        +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>');
        }
    });
}
```

And the `popover-content` is this:

```
<ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
</ul>
```

But it is not working. However if I add this links directly into `<ul>` it works. But I want to add it dynamically so I can assign the id to each link (button).

Anyone? Why append is not working in this case?

**EDIT**

@Arex had a good point that `display:none` state was not changing. I changed my function and it looks like this:

```
function showPopover(element) {
    $(element).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {

            var popover =  $('#popover-content');

            popover.show();

            popover = popover.append('<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>'
                                        +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Activate</a>'
                                        +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>');
            return popover;   
        }
    });
}
```

And it works but very strange...

When I click first time it looks like everything is fine:

[image: State1]
After that when I try to close that popover, it extends (doubles) the content:

[image: state2]

And finally when I try to open it again, it shows empty popover :/

[image: State3]

**EDIT 2**

I added `popover.empty()` and it works.. But when I open and close popover 2-3 times, it becomes empty. This starts to be annoying -.-

[image]

Comment: Which element/action triggers `showPopover()`?

Comment: I've edited my question. It is the button with `onclick="showPopover(this)"`

Comment: Where does your display:none property change?

Comment: Tried to create a fiddle from your example and it shows `item.name` as undefined. Can you please post complete HTML and jQuery code with static values? So that we can help further.

Comment: `item.name` is a part of JSON which I get from backend.

Comment: @Arex i totally forgot about that. Thx. But now it appends the list on my page, not in the popover box :/.

Comment: @harunB10 I have provided the code for the function try that. Include display:block wherever required

Comment: Technically, if you want to add some links into `UL` tags, then try wrapping them up in `LI`.

Comment: @RaviManiyar true, but that is not necessary

Comment: No, @Arex - the contents inside UL must be wrapped in LI. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul#6056168

Comment: Hence `<ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="">
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a></li><li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Activate</a></li><li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></li></ul>` is only valid in this case.

Comment: @RaviManiyar Try running this in fiddle:<ul id="popover-content">
  <a>List item 1</a>
  <a>List item 2</a>
  <a>List item 3</a>
</ul> . It is not 'valid' but it will work.

Comment: It will definitely work but its totally against W3C standard.

Comment: I edited my question with screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/3363/) fiddle for you. This should help you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="appendTarget"></div>

<ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var isMyPopoverShown = false;

function myPop(element) {
  if(isMyPopoverShown === false) {
    $(element).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            $('#popover-content').html('<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a></li>'
            +'<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Activate</a></li>'
            +'<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></li>');
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
    });
  }  
  $(element).popover('toggle');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('#appendTarget').append('<div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Item' + 
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="myPop(this);" data-trigger="manual"><b style="color: red">Button</b></button></div>');

  $(".btn").on('shown.bs.popover',function(){
    isMyPopoverShown = true;
  });

});
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are keeping on appending more and more `<a>` to the popover on every click.
Do this instead:
Create a variable `i` and initialise it as `i=1`(Do this outside the onclick triggered function or it will keep on re-initialising to 1 ). Inside your function check if `i==1` if it is true use your current code and increment it by 1.
else if check `i` is divisible by 2 -> if it is true hide it,
else -> show it.

```
        function showPopover(element) {
            if(i==1){
            $(element).popover({
                html: true,
                content: function() {

                    var popover =  $('#popover-content');

                    popover.show();i=i+1;

                    popover = popover.append('<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>'
                                                +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Activate</a>'
                                                +'<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>');
                    return popover;   
                }
            });
          }
        else if(i%2==0)
    {
       $(element).popover({
            html: true,
            content: function() {

                var popover =  $('#popover-content');

                popover.hide();i=i+1;


                return popover;   
            }
        });
    }
   else{
        $(element).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {

            var popover =  $('#popover-content');

            popover.show();i=i+1;


            return popover;   
        }
    });}
        }
```

Comment: This function is not working. I edited my questiion with screenshots.