# How to fix button isn't adding a new <li>

Tags: javascript

I'm just facing a problem while clicking on **"Add New Item"** button, javascript won't add me a new line `(<li>)` in `<ul>`

I tried making a variable for `<ul>` with **id="change"** which is **document.getElementById("change");**

On the other hand, I just added an **"addEventListener"** to this variable, so while I click on this button, a function named **"achange"** will start working, and add a new line to the `<ul>`

```js
var icounter = 1;
var c = document.getElementById("change");
c.addEventListener("click", achange);

function achange() {
  ulist.innerHTML += "<li> New Item " + icounter + "</li>";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header"> List that contains items. </h1>
<button id="change">Add New Item </button>
<ul type="square" id="ulist">
  <li> Pizza </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Burger </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Chicken Dinner </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Salad </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
</ul>
```

I'm expecting to add a line which says : **"New Item 0"** , but nothing happens, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: use document.getElementById('ulist').innerHTML += ....

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Have you put your `addEventListener` in the `<head>`, *without* wrapping it in a `Window.load` (or equivalent)? Also, `<hr>` **is not a valid child of `<ul>`.** Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @TylerRoper Not all browsers support id access by properties on the window. OP's browser probably doesn't support that.

Comment: @sjdm Take another look at OP's code. He's already doing `innerHTML += ...`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That makes more sense.

Comment: I didn't even realise you could do that. It seems wrong somehow.

Comment: Your HTML is **invalid**. `hr` cannot be a direct child element of `ul`, only `li` is allowed.

Comment: Funny enough, despite its lack of support across all browsers, named access on the `window` object is actually specifically *included* in the [HTML5 spec]( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object), though it clarifies: *"As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use `document.getElementById()`"*

Comment: @connexo so removing hr may fix my code?

Comment: No, but invalid HTML is inacceptable nonetheless.

Comment: @connexo i just removed hr and nothing happened

Comment: @connexo so what should i do to fix this button?

Comment: @RaphaelEid Change `ulist.innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("ulist").innerHTML` and see if that resolves your issue. If not, then it's likely because your click event handler is not waiting for the page to load.

Comment: @TylerRoper i tried it sir, nothing happens, so the problem is from webpage/browser or my code?

Comment: The JavaScript you've provided - is it in the `<head>` of your document? And, if so, is it wrapped in another event?

Comment: @jonathana Using inline event listeners is widely considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this without using `appendChild`:

```js
var iCounter = 1;

var c = document.getElementById("change");
c.addEventListener("click", achange);

function achange() {

  var ulist = document.getElementById('ulist');
  
  ulist.innerHTML += '<li> New Item ' + (iCounter++) + ' </li><hr align="left" width="20%">';
  
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header"> List that contains items. </h1>
<button id="change">Add New Item </button>
<ul type="square" id="ulist">
  <li> Pizza </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Burger </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Chicken Dinner </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
  <li> Salad </li>
  <hr align="left" width="20%">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting things at the wrong time. I would also recommend a different way of appending your items rather than append text into `innerHTML`.

Within your function (when you add the item) you'll want to get the reference to your `ul` and append children from there. This also gives you the opportunity to get the count of `li`s for numbering the next item (if you wish)

Also, as pointed out by others, not all browsers will support the id reference you're trying to do with `ulist`

Another thing to mention here is that `hr` is not a valid decendent of `ul`. If you really want the `hr`, you should use css or put the hr within the `li` ([Is anything except LI's allowed in a UL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056142/is-anything-except-lis-allowed-in-a-ul))

```js
const addNewItem = () => {
  const list = document.getElementById('ulist');
  const liCount = list.querySelectorAll('li').length;
  const hr = document.createElement('hr');
  hr.setAttribute('align', 'left');
  hr.setAttribute('width', '20%');
  const newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerText = `Item # ${liCount + 1}`;
  newLi.append(hr);
  list.appendChild(newLi);
};

document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', addNewItem);
```

```html
<h1 id="header"> List that contains items. </h1>
<button id="change">Add New Item </button>
<ul type="square" id="ulist">
<li> Pizza </li> <hr align="left" width="20%">
<li> Burger </li> <hr align="left" width="20%"> 
<li> Chicken Dinner </li> <hr align="left" width="20%">
<li> Salad </li> <hr align="left" width="20%">
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and I know that OP's example includes the `<hr>`s, but it's worth pointing out that they're completely invalid. The only acceptable direct child of a `<ul>` element is an `<li>` element.

Comment: Good point. I personally would have used css for that part, but added it in anyways.

Comment: @mwilson i used 
#change{
background-color:black;
border-radius:50%;
padding-left:50px;
height:20%;
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:red;
padding-right:37px;
}

Comment: What's invalid about it?

Comment: `list.appendChild(hr)` appends a disallowed element to `list`. The fact that OPs initial HTML is already invalid does not justify suggesting Javascript that creates equally invalid results.

Comment: I added it in there for @Tyler Roper's feedback. Read the comments.

Comment: You misinterpreted @TylerRoper's first comment. He criticizes the same as I do.

Comment: @connexo Is correct. I was suggesting that you point OP in the right direction by removing any invalid HTML.

Comment: Let alone the fact that `align` and `width` are deprecated attributes, and have been so since the end of WW II.

Comment: Tough crowd today. The answer is updated to address all concerns

Comment: Eh. I just think if someone asks you to change their oil and you notice they're missing a tire, the least you could do is say somethin'. In any case, the answer is better now for mentioning it.

Comment: The answer is still creating invalid HTML. Fixing that is not optional, as your current edit suggests "*you should*".

Comment: Feel free to correct it or provide another answer if you're that concerned about it.

Comment: You are responsible for your answers, not others.

Answer (score 0):

4 issues with your code:

1. Your HTML was invalid as I commented on your question. I removed the `hr` elements.
2. Instead of working with strings and innerHTML, on simple elements it is often easier (and almost always much faster) to use `document.createElement` and `appendChild` methods.
3. Your `button` had no `type` attribute, so it was `type="submit"` (which is the default type).
4. You need to make sure the Javascript executes only after the DOM has been parsed, otherwise `change` and `ulist` are `undefined`. There is several ways to achieve that:

   - Wrap the functionality in a function that gets executed on  `DOMContentLoaded` event (see below code).
   - Make sure the Javascript is positioned at the end of the `body`, right before the closing tag `</body>`.
   - Put your Javascript in an external file `script.js` and reference that in your HTML using `<script src="path/to/script.js" defer></script>`.

```js
var icounter = 1;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  change.addEventListener("click", achange);

  function achange() {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `New Item ${icounter++}`;
    ulist.appendChild(li);
  }
})
```

```html
<h1 id="header"> List that contains items. </h1>
<button id="change" type="button">Add New Item </button>
<ul type="square" id="ulist">
  <li> Pizza </li>
  <li> Burger </li>
  <li> Chicken Dinner </li>
  <li> Salad </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your time, is there any way to run it without using "let" and "textContent" and "appendChild" ? or this is the only way?

Comment: `li` should be `const`. The value of `li` is never changed.

Comment: @mwilson Thanks for pointing out. Even though this is kind of personal preference, I agree and have changed it.

Comment: @RaphaelEid You can also use `innerHTML` the way you tried instead. I mentioned the cons for that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without `appendChild` and `const` and `$` :

I just added `onclick="functionName()"` on the `button` and it worked.

```
<h1 id="header"> List that contains items. </h1>
<button id="change" onclick="achange()">Add New Item </button>
<ul type="square" id="ulist">
<li> Pizza </li> <hr>
<li> Burger </li> <hr>
<li> Chicken Dinner </li> <hr>
<li> Salad </li> <hr>
</ul>
```

```
var icounter = 1;
    function achange(){
    document.getElementById("ulist").innerHTML += "<li> New Item " +icounter +"</li> <hr>";
    icounter++;
    }
```