# Ordered and Nested Lists (Letters and Numbers)

Tags: html, list, medical

So, I'm creating this list, and this is how I need it go, and HTML is not having it, so I was wondering if anyone knew any runarounds.

A.

1. 
2. a. 
   b. 
   c. 
   d. 
   e. 
   f. 
   g. 
   h. 
   i. 
   j.

Logically, the next *uppercase* letter would be "B", but HTML seems to have other plans for my list (going back to "A"), so my list should continue as such:

B.

1. 
2. a.

and so on...

Here's what I have currently. I'm not removing all the medical mumbo jumbo just because there's a lot already and I don't really feel like going back to delete all of it for this.

```
<h2>Chapter-specific Guidelines with Coding Examples</h2>
<ol class="upletter">
<li style="font-weight: bold">Human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) infections</li>
<ol class="number">
    <li style="font-weight: bold">Code only confirmed cases</li>
    <p>Code only confirmed cases of HIV infection/illness. This is an exception to the hospital inpatient guideline Section II, H. <br>In this context, "confirmation" does not require documentation of positive serology or culture for HIV; the provider's diagnostic statement that the patient is HIV positive or has an HIV-related illness is sufficient.</p>
    <div style="background-color: mediumpurple; padding: 8px 14px">
        Patient being seen for hypothyroidism with possible HIV infection<br>
        <b>E03.9 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hypothyroidism, unspecified</b><br>
        <i>Explanation:</i> Only the hypothyroidism is coded in this scenario because it has not been confirmed that an HIV infection is present.
    </div>
    <li style="font-weight: bold">Selection and sequencing of HIV codes</li>
    <ol class="downletter">
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Patient admitted for HIV-related condition</li>

        <p>If a patient is admitted for an HIV-related condition, the principal diagnosis should be B20, Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV) disease followed by additional diagnosis codes for all reported HIV-related conditions.
            An exception to this guideline is if the reason for admission is hemolytic-uremic syndrome associated with HIV disease. Assign code D59.31, Infection-associated hemolytic-uremic syndrome, followed by code B20, Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease.</p>

        <div style="background-color: mediumpurple; padding: 8px 14px">HIV with CMV<br>
            <b>B20 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease <br>
                B25.9 Cytomegaloviral disease, unspecified</b><br>
            <i>Explanation:</i> Cytomegaloviral infection is an HIV related condition, so the HIV diagnosis code is reported first, followed by the code for the CMV.
        </div>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Patient with HIV disease admitted for unrelated condition</li>
        <p>If a patient with HIV disease is admitted for an unrelated condition (such as a traumatic injury), the code for the unrelated condition (e.g., the nature of injury code) should be the principal diagnosis. Other diagnoses would be B20 followed by additional diagnosis codes for all reported HIV-related conditions.</p>
        <div style="background-color: mediumpurple; padding: 8px 14px">
            Sprain of the internal collateral ligament, right ankle; HIV<br>
            <b>593.491A &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Sprain of other ligament of right ankle, initial encounter</b><br>
            <b>B20 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease</b><br>
            <i>Explanation:</i> The ankle sprain is not related to HIV, so it is the first-listed diagnosis code, and HIV is reported secondarily.
        </div>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Whether the patient is newly diagnosed
        <p>Whether the patient is newly diagnosed or has had previous admissions/encounters for HIV conditions is irrelevant to the sequencing decision.</p></li>

        <div style="background-color: mediumpurple; padding: 8px 14px">
            Newly diagnosed multiple cutaneous Kaposi's sarcoma lesions in previously diagnosed HIV disease<br>
            <b>B20 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease</b><br>
            <b>C46.0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Kaposi's sarcoma of skin</b><br>
            <i>Explanation:</i> Even though the HIV was diagnosed on a previous encounter, it is still sequenced first when coded with an HIV-related condition. Kaposi's sarcoma is an HIV-related condition.
        </div>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Asymptomatic human immunodeficiency virus
        <p>Z21, Asymptomatic human immunodeficiency virus [HIV infection status, is to be applied when the patient without any documentation of symptoms is listed as being "HIV positive," "known HIV," "HIV test positive," or similar terminology. Do not use this code if the term "AIDS" or "HIV disease" is used or if the patient is treated for any HIV-related illness or is described as having any condition(s) resulting from his/her HIV positive status; use B20 in these cases.</p></li>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Patients with inconclusive HIV serology</li>
            <p>Patients with inconclusive HIV serology, but no definitive diagnosis or manifestations of the illness, may be assigned code R75, Inconclusive laboratory evidence of human immunodeficiency virus [HIV].</p>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Previously diagnosed HIV-related illness </li>
            <p>Patients with any known prior diagnosis of an HIV-related illness should be coded to B20. Once a patient has developed an HIV-related illness, the patient should always be assigned code B20 on every subsequent admission/encounter. Patients previously diagnosed with any HIV illness (B20) should never be assigned to R75 or Z21, Asymptomatic human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] infection status.</p>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">HIV infection in pregnancy, childbirth and the puerperium</li>
            <p>During pregnancy, childbirth or the puerperium, a patient admitted (or presenting for a health care encounter) because of an HIV-related illness should receive a principal diagnosis code of 098.7-, Human immunodeficiency [HIV) disease complicating pregnancy, childbirth and the puerperium, followed by B20 and the code(s) for the HIV-related illness(es). Codes from Chapter 15 always take sequencing Chapter 1. Certain Infectious and Parasitic Diseases priority.</p>
            <p>Patients with asymptomatic HIV infection status admitted (or presenting for a health care encounter) during pregnancy, childbirth, or the puerperium should receive codes of 098.7 - and Z21.</p>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">Encounters for testing for HIV</li>
            <p>If a patient is being seen to determine his/her HIV status, use code Z11.4, Encounter for screening for human immunodeficiency virus [HIV]. Use additional codes for any associated high-risk behavior, if applicable.</p>
            <p>If a patient with signs or symptoms is being seen for HIV testing, code the signs and symptoms. An additional counseling code 271.7, Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] counseling, may be used if counseling is provided during the encounter for the test</p>
            <p>When a patient returns to be informed of his/her HIV test results and the test result is negative, use code Z71.7, Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] counseling. </p>
            <p>If the results are positive, see previous guidelines and assign codes as appropriate.</p>
        <li style="font-weight: bold">HIV managed by antiretroviral medication</li>
            <p>If a patient with documented HIV disease, HIV-related illness or AIDS is currently managed on antiretroviral medications, assign code B20, Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease. Code Z79.899, Other long term (current) drug therapy, may be assigned as an additional code to identify the long-term (current) use of antiretroviral medications.</p>
        <li style="font-weight: bold"><i>Encounter for HIV Prophylaxis Measure</i></li>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">When a patient is seen for administration of pre-exposure prophylaxis medication for HIV, assign code Z29.81, Encounter for HIV pre-exposure prophylaxis. Pre-exposure prophylaxis (PrEP) is intended to prevent infection in people who are at risk for getting HIV through sex or injection drug use. Any risk factors for HIV should also be coded.</p>

    </ol>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol class="upletter">
<li>Next</li>
</ol>
```

It's so easily customizable in Microsoft Word!! :'(

Thanks everyone in advance for your input and your solutions (if it's even possible)!

PS - In case you were curious what this list is for, I'm making an online version of my mom's medical coding book so she can look up medical codes faster simply by typing in the condition found in the individual's medical chart and finding its corresponding code. Unfortunately, there's 22 chapters and just over 1200 pages. She better enjoy this!! She was complaining a few months ago to my brother (who's going to school currently for the same thing) about how tedious looking up medical codes are.

Comment: Where is your html that you reference?

Comment: *the next uppercase letter would be "B"* Why? What are doing to create this lists?

Comment: [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)

Comment: Can you show a sample of your HTML? At least include the A and B items, no need to include all of a through j, no need to provide all the text in the items

Comment: I added it in my original post. Where it says "Next" at the end is where the "B" should be.

Comment: Note that any content that is [**not** a `<li>` is invalid as a child of an `<ol>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6056190/785241); in other words, the above is invalid html.  Content may go in li elements, but any direct children of ol or ul elements must be `li`s

Comment: Your "B" `<li>` should be in the *same* `<ol>` as the "A" one, do not start a new `<ol>`

Answer (score 3):

You need an ordered list `<ol>` which by default will order them by numbers.

you can use the `type="a"` attribute in HTML to change it to lower case letters. Alternatively, you can change it with CSS by adding the following property: `list-style-type: lower-alpha;`

These are the options an unordered list has:

| Sign | Type |
| --- | --- |
| a | lowercase letters |
| A | uppercase letters |
| i | lowercase Roman numerals |
| I | uppercase Roman numerals |
| 1 | numbers (default) |

The important thing is, that a "sub-list"  must be still within the parent list point `<li>`

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li>1st 1st-level list item
    <ol>2nd-level sublist
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2
        <ol type="a">
          <li>must be part of the 2nd main list point</li>
          <li>must be part of the 2nd main list point</li>
          <li>must be part of the 2nd main list point</li>
          <li>must be part of the 2nd main list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>for the 3rd main list point you need to add a new li</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>2nd 1st level list-item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys for a quick fix!! Just had to add in an extra <ol> tag and add in a list item to get the B

Comment: @BrandonBlessing Note that you should always close the `ol` element within the same tag that you open it in.  Not doing so can affect the html in a bad way.  It is not clear from your comment whether you did this or not, and thus this tip is based on your posted html.

Comment: Everything was proper. I would've noticed a red tag indicating an element wasn't finished properly. I just needed another layer so to speak to allow for the next letter.

Comment: @BrandonBlessing If your html is largely unchanged from what you posted in your question, I assure you it was not proper at all.