# HTML: Is it valid to put element other than <li> into <ul>?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use any other TAG inside <ul> along with <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li)

Or say, `<UL>` can only contain `<LI>`? or it will be invalid?
I looked up the definition however seem they did not specify this.
see

> http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/ul

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li

Comment: Permitted contents: zero or more li elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

Comment: Sorry charlie i just found the link you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly inside a <ul> or <ol> element, you can only have <li> elements and other <ul> or <ol> elements.  All other tags need to be inside of <li>'s.