# Which DOM elements can be child of tr?

Tags: html, dom

I have problem becouse I want to surround some of `td` inside `tr` so I need to know.

Which DOM elements can be child of tr? (I know `div` cannot.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

W3C specify this stuff. For `tr`, you can find it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TR). Basically, only `th` and `td` elements can be *direct* contents of `tr`.

If you want *other* stuff inside your table, it has to go *inside* the `td` or `th` elements. For example, `td` can contain flow elements, including `div`.

Answer (score 8):

[The HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#tr) states:

> #### Permitted contents
>
> Zero or more of: one `td` element, or one `th` element

`<tr>` elements can contain *only* `<td>`s and `<th>`s.

Comment: `<tr>` elements *can* contain both at the same time.

Comment: @Blender - Well, you're really reading a reference, not the spec. The [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-tr-element.html#the-tr-element) says "Zero or more td or th elements". The [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5) says `<!ELEMENT TR - O (TH|TD)+ -- table row -->`.  But you're misreading the reference; it says "zero or more of: one td element, or one th element". Note the position of the colon. It's (one td element or one th element) sero or more times. But in any case, it's an easy test to check it in a validator.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is very similar to that of `ul` which I have described in detail at: [Can we use any other TAG inside <ul> along with <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li/60885802#60885802) so I recommend you read that first.

Notably, the less obvious point is that ASCII whitespace does not form text nodes, while any non-whitespace characters forms and illegal text node, which cannot be children of `table`.

Then, in the "Content model" of `tr` in the current standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element we see:

> Content model:
>   Zero or more `td`, `th`, and script-supporting elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about a DOM tree constructed from an HTML document that conforms to HTML specifications, then the answer is `td` and `th`, as explained in paxdiablo’s answer.

But you *can* modify a DOM tree as you like, in scripting. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<table border>
<tr><td>foo <td>bar
</table>
<script>
var p = document.createElement('div');
p.innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].appendChild(p);
</script>
```

This will make a `div` element a child of a `tr` element. You could even put create some `td` elements and make them children of the `div` element.

Whether this makes sense and whether it might confuse browsers is a different issue. And browsers will not parse normally HTML markup where e.g. `tr` element contains a `div` element as a child – parsers are not prepared to handle such cases. Grouping `td` elements (in any other way than making them children of a `tr`) is not possible in HTML markup. But in the DOM, you can create odd trees.

If just want to deal with some `td` elements in a special way, give them a `class`.