# Vue - Using v-for twice to render a tables rows and cells?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to use Vue to render a table with rows but have the cells as a component.

I have made [a working example](http://codepen.io/craigvantonder/pen/RoqrLO) of what I would like to see as the end result and have some code relating to how I think that I could go about this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, rindex) in people">
        <td>{{ rindex }}</td>
        <cell v-for="(value, vindex, rindex) in row" :value="value" :vindex="vindex" :rindex="rindex"></cell>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <template id="template-cell">
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </template>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Register component
Vue.component('cell', {
  template: '#template-cell',
  name: 'row-value',
  props: ['value', 'vindex', 'rindex']
  // In here I would like to access value, vindex and rindex
});
// Start application
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: [
      {id: 3, name: 'Bob', age: 27},
      {id: 4, name: 'Frank', age: 32},
      {id: 5, name: 'Joe', age: 38}
    ]
  }
});
```

This is because, in the Vue [documentation on v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for) they show the example:

```
And another for the index:

<div v-for="(value, key, index) in object">
  {{ index }}. {{ key }} : {{ value }}
</div>
```

So logically thinking, I should be able to get the rows index in the cell component without too much issue but [this is not so](http://codepen.io/craigvantonder/pen/KNrMgY) as it comes up with a bunch of errors indicating that the values are undefined.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here then I would be greatly appreciate it as I'm out of ideas with this problem but would really like to understand how to implement this correctly.

(Note: the reason for me wanting to render the cells in the component is to register the change of values, [see the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135610/2110294) to another question that I asked here if you're interested)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to enclose your `cell` component inside an `template` element, this is because table in HTML expects [only td inside tr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634766), when it sees `cell`, it will not render it(see similar problem with Angular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556489)). However template can be used here as a content fragment and after vue compiles, it will add `tr` in place of cell in the HTML.

```
  <tr v-for="(row, rindex) in people">
    <td>{{ rindex }}</td>
    <template>
       <cell  v-for="(value, vindex) in row" :value="value" :vindex="vindex" :rindex="rindex" ></cell>
    </template>
  </tr>
```

see working pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpRpeq).

Comment: Thanks for the codepen example. I was not sure if custom labels like `rindex` can be used as an iterator in `v-for`, and ended up writing a completely different answer.

Comment: When I was trying to do this I found something similar but it used v-for in the template tag. I figured this to be a bit of a hack to excluded it from my question but when you say what you have and thinking about it now, it's a logical way to approach this and somewhat of an odd case when dealing with tr and td tags as you can't wrap them in any other tags or the table will not render correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can replace `index` with `rindex` in the `v-for` constructor. If the implementation of `v-for` expects the string labels for `key` and `index`, then your `rindex` and `vindex` will not work.

I see another problem, as quoted from the reference page in question: [List Rendering in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for)

> When iterating over an object, the order is based on the key enumeration order of Object.keys(), which is not guaranteed to be consistent across JavaScript engine implementations.

Therefore, your first cell may have (id, key, name) in that order, while your second cell may have (name, id, key) - different order. Therefore, the best way is to **avoid object iterator** for `cell` and explicitly define the order of appearance as follows:

```html
<tr v-for="(person, index) in people">
    <td>{{ index }}</td>
    <cell :value="index" valueType="index" :rowIndex="index"></cell>
    <cell :value="person.id" valueType="id" :rowIndex="index"></cell>
    <cell :value="person.name" valueType="name" :rowIndex="index"></cell>
</tr>
```

Now your cell component definition needs to be modified as:

```js
Vue.component("cell", {
    template: "#template-cell",
    name: "row-value",
    props: ["value", "valueType", "rowIndex"],
    // your component code here...
})
```

Now you can use `valueType` and `rowIndex` inside your cell component.

Comment: I did notice the note when reading the docs and experienced this to my bewilderment in the past so what you have said does make sense to me, thank you. Two questions, one is that should there not be a prop `"value"` and also, this is a noob question but I mean logically thinking, if I create a listener on each cell it's going to take more resources than creating it per row or does it make no difference?

Comment: My apologies, there should be a `value` field also in `props`. I forgot about it. I will update the answer to include value in props. And for second question regarding performance / resource consumption, yes - you will consume a bit more memory on the browser. I think it does not make much difference as Vue handles resources very well, thus allowing us to create an easy-to-maintain app. Check this out: http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=316