# Paragraph element prepending not appending to table in django html

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using the Django Web Framework and I have a html table displaying some fields from one of my tables. If there are no fields to display (records in a queryset), I pass variable = "0" from python.

I want to append text to the table in this case so it appears **underneath my table**. But it's appearing **above** my table....

```
<div class="1" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="1" class="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
        {% ifequal variable "0" %}
            <p>No items to show</p>
        {% else %}
            <--append some fields-->
        {% endifnotequal %}
    </table>
</div>
```

If I'm appending the fields this works fine they appear as expected, but in the other case it prepends above the table instead...

Why? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<p>` inside a `<tr>` only `<td>` and `<th>` are allowed.

You'd want to change it to:

```
<div class="1" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="1" class="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
    {% ifequal variable "0" %}
        </table>
        <p>No items to show</p>
    {% else %}
        <--append some fields-->
    {% endifnotequal %}
</div>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634715/which-dom-elements-can-be-child-of-tr) might be helpful for you too

Comment: Ah this did it. Because I append fields potentially I have moved the </table> inside the tag. Thank you!!

Comment: Ah that makes sense then, i rejected your edit sorry before i saw this comment. If you edit it again i can approve, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not doing this correctly. I think there is a tag for putting text below tables, could it be ?

Use the  tag at the end (this is a table specific tag, like   and ).

But you will need to use this CSS:

```
caption {
    caption-side: bottom;
}
```

You can check this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMzPjb