# Can wrapping a div or an anchor tag around a <LI> still be considered valid html structure

Tags: html

I have also noticed a website I've been working with has a `<ul>` structure list written incorrectly. I believe this code does not conform to normal HTML Standards.

Currently the code is written in such a fashion.

```
<ul>

<a href="#"><li>message 1</li></a>

<a href="#"><li>message 2</li></a>

<a href="#"><li>message 3</li></a>

</ul>
```

Surely the correct HTML format should be

```
<ul>

<li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>

<li><a href="#">message 2</a></li>

<li><a href="#">message 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

My Question is..
 if you wrap a div or an anchor tag around a

```
<li>
```

does this still make the html valid?

The reason why I'm **guessing** it was coded in such a fashion was to make the li clickable.

What is the correct standard for the `<ul>` list, can it be written in different ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use any other TAG inside <ul> along with <li>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li)

Comment: The question is wrapping a div or anchor tag around a <li> is this still valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not valid, though it often works.

Yes, the reason most people do like this is to make it clickable.

There is many ways to make any element besides an anchor clickable, where wrapping an anchor around it is the most used.

This is valid for all non block level elements, but will likely work on all element level types because of [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

For block level elements (can also be used on inline elements), one can do like this, to make the whole element clickable

HTML

```
<div class="clickable"><a href='....'></a></div>
```

CSS

```
.clickable a {
  display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%;   /*  fill the parent  */
}
```

---

An alternative when one just can't use an anchor and still need it clickable, would be by using a click handler, like this, using jQuery.

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {
  // Do something here on click
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - No, it's not valid.

If you want the entire `<li>` to be a clickable link, set the `<a>` to `display:block` in your CSS.

Comment: If `li` have a height higher than the anchor text, a height is needed on the anchor as well, or it won't fill, ... and setting it to `display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%` would be more appropriate to keep it to its initial element type as possible

Comment: That's true. My proposed solution only works if the height of the `li` is determined by it's content.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use tags outside li and its valid but we prefer to use it inside li

the difference between your code is:

1) if you use this code `<a href="#"><li>message 1</li></a>`
the li and every thing inside it its a link.

2) if you use this `<li><a href="#">message 2</a></li>`
just the text is link.

Comment: It is **not** valid to have anything but `li` as a direct child of `ul`

Comment: why?? im used it in many projects and its work perfectly, i know thats not prefer to use it like this but sometimes im force to use it

Comment: Because you do, doesn't make it valid, no one said it doesn't work, **but** it is not valid ... run it through a validator (and check w3c specs.) and you'll see ... and you are most likely never forced to use it, if you know all that can be used instead

Comment: Content for UL - "[Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)"