# Align input fields on the same line

Tags: css, reactjs

I have three input fields in a form and I want to put them on the same line.

[image]

The whole section looks like this:

```
          <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">
            <form>
              <input
                placeholder='input 1'
                className="form-control" 
                onKeyDown={(e) => addScore(e)}
                style={{width: '50%'}}
              ></input>

              <input
                placeholder='input 2'
                className="form-control" 
                style={{width:'20%', float:'right'}}
              ></input>
              <input
                placeholder='input 3'
                className="form-control" 
                style={{width:'20%', float:'right'}}
              ></input>

            </form>
          </a>
```

How would I do it in css?

Comment: Can you show us the css?

Comment: are you use bootstrap & ver ? show your css also

Comment: Hey my css is in `style` for all 3 input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I see, You want the input fields like this
[image: inputs]

---

For that you need to add give your input1 `width:50%`, input2 `width:20%` and input3 `width:20%`.

And this is absolutely right, But I think there is some issue with the class of `form-control`, or maybe you should add `width:100%` or `width:inherit` & `display:flex`

Here is how I achieved this:

```css
a{
  width:100vw;
}
form{
  width:100vw;
}
.i1{
  width:50%;
}
.i2{
  width:20%;
}
.i3{
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">
            <form>
              <input
                placeholder='input 1'
                class="form-control i1"
              ></input>

              <input
                placeholder='input 2'
                class="form-control i2" 
              ></input>
              <input
                placeholder='input 3'
                class="form-control i3" 
              ></input>

            </form>
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I do not recommend wrapping your form or any element for that matter with `a` tags. Although this works, this is not considered valid HTML

> Read answers here about `a` tags validity: [Anchor Tag Validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333239/can-wrapping-a-div-or-an-anchor-tag-around-a-li-still-be-considered-valid-html)

As for your question, I'm assuming you're using bootstrap, you can try this out:

```css
.form-background {
  background: #cfe2ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-background p-2 d-inline-block">
  <form>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input One" onKeyDown="{(e) => addScore(e)}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Two">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Input 3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I don't recommend hard coding your width unless you're planning on using pure css later on, which I would then recommend learning more about `Flexbox` and `CSS Grid`, you're already using bootstrap, so might as well make use of it

Answer (score -1):

Just added `float: right` to `input 2` and `input 3`.