# Nth-child() selector alternative solution in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So we want to access **-n+3** `li` elements in a list (if there are different types of elements before the `li` elements we want to access is a detail we do not care about) and I used the following way:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <style>
            li:nth-child(-n+3) {
                background: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>

        <p>An unordered list:</p>

        <ul>
            <h1>heading</h1>
            <li>coffee</li>
            <li>tea</li>
            <li>water</li>
            <li>coca-cola</li>
            <li>sprite</li>
            <li>orange juice</li>
            <li>beer</li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

And it works fine, however in Explorer 8 and earlier versions, `nth-child()` selector is not supported. So how can we access the **-n+3** `li` elements without using the pseudo class `nth-child()`?

Comment: ...who uses exporer 8 or earlier versions today?

Comment: Thats not the point, the point is to find another way to access the specific li elements without the usage of nth-child(). I wrote that to avoid the question about which browser i am using. Lets just say i am using explorer 8 for educational reasons :)

Comment: You shouldn't use tags other than `li` as a direct child of `ul`: [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2). HTML validator will mark this as invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). They work from IE7+.

**Notes:**

- You [shouldn't be using `h1` tag as a direct child of any `ul`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161337/can-we-use-any-other-tag-inside-ul-along-with-li). But if that's how your structure is and you can't modify it then you can use `:first-child + li, :first-child + li + li`.
- `:nth-child(-n+3)` generally would select the first 3 children of a parent.  In your demo, since the first child is a `h1` and since you've also attached the element type (`li`) to the `nth-child(-n+3)` the `h1` doesn't get selected and only the two `li` that follow it are selected. The selector that I've mentioned in Note 1 will do the same (that is, it will select the first two `li` that follow the first child - which is, the `h1` tag - irrespective of how many children the `ul` has).

**Demo 1:** (without any other tag directly inside `ul`)

```css
li:first-child,
li:first-child + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>and so on..</li>
</ul>
```

**Demo 2:** (with your structure)

```css
ul :first-child + li,
ul :first-child + li + li {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(-n+3){
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<p>An unordered list:</p>
<ul>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <li>coffee</li>
  <li>tea</li>
  <li>water</li>
  <li>coca-cola</li>
  <li>sprite</li>
  <li>orange juice</li>
  <li>beer</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But one more thing, is -n+3 always gonna choose the first 2 li elements regardless of how many we have? Cauze if not then your answer is correct but only for the above example. Tell me if I got something wrong

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos: Your understanding is not fully correct on the `:nth-child(-n+3)`. That selector selects the first 3 children of the parent but since you've attached the element type `li` to it and since the first element is not a `li`, it doesn't select the first child. The snippet (second) in my answer will do the same thing :) It selects the first and second `li` elements which are the siblings of the first child of the parent (which is the `h1`).